# Category Entries

Tags: entries, category

Another easy question for you all.... 
I'm trying to display all entries in a specific category. I'm using the below code from the Craft site, but not sure what I'm missing. I'm replacing the "entries" in the output section with the category name.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the category variable.

In this example, I'm using a slug:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug('catSlug') %}
```

So full code:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug('catSlug') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Bravo...... you guys on here are so helpful. I really appreciate all the help..

One more, if I want to limit/offset the output.? 

Thanks Again..

Comment: Found the second part out... 
Thanks again.

Comment: I just started using Craft myself. So learning together is a good thing! Glad you got it figured out. Everything seems to work around the different content models. Once you get a grasp of that, it falls into place.